# jQuery filter items with both a checkbox and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, onchange

I have a list I want a filter, I have the checkboxes working as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765192/jquery-filter-unordered-list-by-class-name-onchange).

On my page I already had the tabs at the top of the page working as shown in the below code and in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/9m8xw/3/).

However they conflict with each other, so currently if you click on xtr1 while the checkbox for col 1 is clicked it removes all col 1 and shows all xtr1.
I want it to be to show all of xtra1 that have col 1 ticked for example. I tried to handle this by adding the variable addchosen as shown below, but can't get it working, how can this best be achieved?

```
<div id="nav">
    <a rel="all"  id="all">All</a>
    <a rel="xtr1" id="xtr1">xtr1</a>
    <a rel="xtr2" id="xtr2">xtr2</a>
    <a rel="xtr3" id="xtr3">xtr3</a>
</div>

<form id="refine-cat">
    <span><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="filtercol">cat 1</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="filtercol">cat 2</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="filtercol">cat 3</span>
</form>
<form id="refine-col">
    <span><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="filtercat">col 1</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="filtercat">col 2</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="filtercat">col 3</span>
    <span><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="filtercat">col 4</span>
</form>
<ul>
    <li class="xtr3 all item cat-3 col-1">col 1 - cat 3 - xtra 3</li>
    <li class="xtr1 all item cat-3 col-1">col 1 - cat 3 - xtra 1</li>
    <li class="xtr1 all item cat-3 col-1">col 1 - cat 3 - xtra 1</li>
</ul>
```

(the list has more items in the fiddle)

JS

```
var chosen = "";

jQuery("#nav a").on("click", function (event) {

    jQuery("#nav a").removeClass("current");
    jQuery(this).addClass("current");

    chosen = jQuery(this).attr("rel");

    jQuery(".item").not("." + chosen).hide();
    jQuery("." + chosen).show();

});


var $items = jQuery('.item');
var $cats = jQuery('#refine-cat input[type=checkbox]');
var $cols = jQuery('#refine-col input[type=checkbox]');

$cols.add($cats).on('change', function (e) {
    var cats = $cats.filter(':checked').map(function(){
        return 'cat-' + (this.value || '')
    }).get();
    var cols = $cols.filter(':checked').map(function(){
        return 'col-' + (this.value || '')
    }).get();

    if(cats.length || cols.length){
        var $fitems = $items;
        var addchosen = "";
        if (chosen) {
            addchosen =', .' + chosen;
        }        
        if(cats.length){
            $fitems = $fitems.filter('.' + cats.join(', .') + addchosen );
        }
        if(cols.length){
            $fitems = $fitems.filter('.' + cols.join(', .'));
        }

        $fitems.show();
        $items.not($fitems).hide();
    } else {
        $items.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code a little bit. There is a cleaner way of doing this but I didn't wanted to change your line of thinking.

So, I've created a function named `refine()` and basically isolated this part of your code and added a filter for chosen also:

```
if(cats.length){
    $fitems = $fitems.filter('.' + cats.join(', .') + addchosen );
}
if(cols.length){
    $fitems = $fitems.filter('.' + cols.join(', .'));
}
```

So this function will be called both on `nav` click and `cols/cats` change, like this:

```
var cats=[], cols=[], $fitems;
var $items = jQuery('.item');
var chosen = "";

function refine() {
    $items.show();
    $fitems = $items;

    if(chosen.length && chosen != 'all') {
        $fitems = $items.filter('.' + chosen);
    }
    if(cats.length){
        $fitems = $fitems.filter('.' + cats.join(', .'));
    }
    if(cols.length){
        $fitems = $fitems.filter('.' + cols.join(', .'));
    }

    $fitems.show();
    $items.not($fitems).hide();
}

jQuery("#nav a").on("click", function (event) {

    jQuery("#nav a").removeClass("current");
    jQuery(this).addClass("current");

    chosen = jQuery(this).attr("rel");

    refine();
});

var $cats = jQuery('#refine-cat input[type=checkbox]');
var $cols = jQuery('#refine-col input[type=checkbox]');

$cols.add($cats).on('change', function (e) {
    cats = $cats.filter(':checked').map(function(){
        return 'cat-' + (this.value || '')
    }).get();
    cols = $cols.filter(':checked').map(function(){
        return 'col-' + (this.value || '')
    }).get();

    refine();
});
```

Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XCFMp/1/)

Comment: Do you know what the syntax (using delegation) would be if the html was loaded from a json file instead of plain html?  
I was trying to apply the answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839225/manipulate-json-data-with-jquery into the change part of your answer but I am getting syntax errors? 
I have tried to replace 
$cols.add($cats).on('change', function (e) { 
with 
jQuery(document).on("change", "$cols.add($cats)", function (event) { 
but I am getting Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $cols.add($cats)

Comment: You could try something like this: jQuery('#refine-cat input[type=checkbox], #refine-col input[type=checkbox]') and I think you'll get the same results as using .add

Comment: and in order for it to work when loading data you'll need to apply the `.on` into an element that will always be there and then pass as a `second argument` the element that you want to trigger at the `change` event. Please provide a dummy fiddle with the json and I'll gladly correct for you. Doesn't really need to load the data, its just easy for me to have something I can look at.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I actually tries the selectors in there as well but haven't been able to get the second argument going, I have done this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/5SUNS/3/ which shows the filter working with static content but not when loading the json, are you able to advise when you get a chance please?

Answer (score 1):

I would n't probably complicate it this much. Here is one way.

```
jQuery("#nav a").on("click", function (event) {
    jQuery("#nav a").removeClass("current");
    jQuery(this).addClass("current").attr("rel");
    if(this.id == 'all') $cats.add($cols).prop('checked', false);
    updateResult();
});


var $items = jQuery('.item');
var $cats = jQuery('#refine-cat input[type=checkbox]');
var $cols = jQuery('#refine-col input[type=checkbox]');

$cols.add($cats).on('change', function () {
   //Do something....
    updateResult();

});

function updateResult() {

    $('ul > li').hide();

    var consArray = [];
    consArray = consArray.concat($('#nav > a.current').map(function () {
        return this.rel;
    }).get());

    consArray = consArray.concat($cats.filter(':checked').map(function () {
        return 'cat-' + this.value;
    }).get());

    consArray = consArray.concat($cols.filter(':checked').map(function () {
        return 'col-' + this.value;
    }).get());

    if(consArray.length)
        $('.' + consArray.join('.')).show();
 }
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5n968/)**

and a simpler version:

```
function updateResult() {
    $('ul > li').hide();
    var consArray =  $('#nav > a.current').add(
                              $cats.filter(':checked')).add(
                              $cols.filter(':checked'))
        .map(function(){
              if(this.nodeName === 'A') return this.rel;
              return this.name.replace(/filter/,'') + '-' + this.value;

           }).get();

    if(consArray.length)
        $('.' + consArray.join('.')).show();
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cR99A/)**