# Manipulate json data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am looking to load json data as html as show in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/5SUNS/) and below.

```
    (function () {
        var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
        $.getJSON(flickerAPI, {
            tags: "mount rainier",
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        })
            .done(function (data) {
            $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
                $("<img>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
                if (i === 3) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    })();
        jQuery("#images img").on("click", function (event) {
            console.log('aaa');
        });
```

I can get the json to load however I can't then get events such as on click to work with data that has been loaded with json, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You want to look at delegated events: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delegate your click events. They're being bound to items in the DOM, and then you're adding new items, and the events are not bound to them.

Try replacing your click binder with this:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#images img", function (event) {
    console.log('aaa');
});
```

You'll want to replace `document` with the lowest-level consistent wrapper to avoid redundant traversal on click.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
    $("#images").on("click", "img",  function (event) {
        console.log('aaa');
    });
```

the element with the id `images` exists when your event binding is attached, but the image elements do not. So using the `on` method, you can pass the `img` elements as a second parameter so that all `img` elements that are added after the page load are properly bound to this event handler.